# Python: how to use timeit?

Tags: python, timeit

I tried to make decorator for method that can count run time of another function in Python

```
def timer(func):
        def smallfunctimer(*args,**kwargs):
            res=func(*args,**kwargs)
            tm=timeit.Timer(lambda:res)
            print("Function time: ", tm)
        return smallfunctimer

@timer
    def deposit(self,amount):
        self.balance+=amount
        self.queue.append(BankTransaction(amount))
```

but when i call it

```
ba=BankAccount(1,100)
ba.deposit(10000000)
```

i get this:

```
Function time:  <timeit.Timer object at 0x0281D370>
```

How may i get run time in seconds?

Answer (score 2):

You created a [`timeit.Timer()` instance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer); you'd need to call a method on that instance for it to actually run the code:

```
print("Function time: ", tm.timeit(1000))
```

would give you the time it took to run the function 1000 times.